# How to get NUnit tests to recognize the Entity Framework used in main project when using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, nunit-3.0

I have 2 projects in my solution that are in adjacent directories.  First one, is the web app that I set as the startup project, and a second one that has the NUnit tests for the web app.  When I try to run the NUnit test I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named 'HPCEntities' could be found in the application config file.
```

I have a copy of the web.config in the directory of the NUnit tests project and it is identical to the one on the web app (which works).

Is there some hidden app.config file that I don't know about that needs the connectionString?  Where would I look.

I have made copies of the web.config file to eliminate the 'no connection string found' error without success.  I made an app.config, which is in the base directory of the NUnits project, that only had the connectionstring and also got no benefit.

I looked under the hood at the .csproj file which had the following only.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>HPC_NUnit_Tests</RootNamespace>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove=".gitignore" />
    <None Remove="Web.config" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RhinoMocks" Version="3.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\HPCv4\HPCv4.csproj" />
      
  </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

The app.config file has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="HPCEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.HPCEntity.csdl|res://*/DataModel.HPCEntity.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.HPCEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data.../>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Just for clarification, my setup method has the following:

```
        private IMasterWipRepository repo;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            HPCEntityContext entity = new HPCEntityContext();
            IRepositoryFactory repoFactory = RepositoryFactory.GetTest(entity);
            repo = repoFactory.GetMasterWipRepo();
        }
```

What is missing or incorrect?

Comment: Can't tell for sure from your post, but it looks like you don't have a test one time setup method that creates the EF context using the connection string in your test project config file. I would also point out that you don't need a separate config file in your test project, just add a link in your test project to the config file from your web project. If you don't want all the content from the web config, you can split config files into smaller chunks and then only include the chunks you want as links.

Comment: A more cogent question might be, why do you want to use EF in your unit tests? I typically create a test data service using moq to avoid dependencies on the DB.

Comment: The reason is that I need to test where certain things are set when they are first entered into the database and all fields are updated properly.  So one set of tests check that it goes to database correctly and everything saves.  Another set of tests checks for other logic flow stuff.

Comment: How would you add the link?  That seems like the simpliest solution.

Comment: You add a link just like you do any existing item, except that once you have selected the config file from the other project, click on the down arrow next to the Add button and select "Add as Link". I don't think that is going to solve your problem, however. You have to manually load the config in your one time setup method and create a context instance, passing in the connectionString read from the config file.

Comment: As to your "need to test where certain things are set when they are first entered into the database and all fields are updated properly", all of that can be accomplished with Moq. Granted, you have to do a bit of extra work to create a test DataService that mocks the DB, but you gain the advantage of not having to reset your DB before each unit test session. As an added bonus, you can ignore the connection string entirely.